# Finding the Jre file on Mac and Linux from java.home

Tags: java, linux, macos, path, invoke

I was able to invoke Java from within Java on Windows from (java.home)/bin/java. But I tried the same code on a Mac, and it didn't work. I presume it wouldn't work on Linux either. What file within java.home do I need to invoke to launch java on Mac and Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same command to invoke java "java" . But first verify that java is installed in your Mac or Linux. Use following command and see what you get

```
user@ubuntu:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
user@ubuntu:~$ ll /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 26 21:54 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
user@ubuntu:~$ ll /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Aug 15 12:43 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java*
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoke `java`. There is no need to type anything in front of it.

By the way, there is no need to type anything in front of `java` on Windows either. You can set your `PATH` environment variable to point to your `java.home` directory.